# Proving claims about sequences by induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am learning how to prove claims about finite sequences right now. Can you help me prove or disprove the following claim?

```
For every n where n greater than or equal to 1, for every 
finite sequence a(0), a(1),...a(n) of n+1 elements, it holds that
```

$$\sum_{j=1}^n (a(j)-a(j-1)) = a(n)-a(0)$$

I know I need to prove this by induction but not sure what my hypothesis and inductive step should look like. Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: Does it work in the "first case" ($n=1$)?

Comment: Yes, a(1) - a(0) = a(1) - a(0)

Comment: Can you write your sum so that the $n^\text{th}$ summand is separated from the sum up to $n-1$?

Comment: Well maybe not for n=1

Comment: Don't need it for $n=1$; that's already handled.

Comment: Not quite sure how to write that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base case $(n=1)$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^1 (a(j)-a(j-1)) &= a(1)-a(0) \\
a(1)-a(1-1) &= \\
a(1)-a(0)   &\overset{\checkmark}{=} 
\end{align*}

Induction $(n>1)$:

Hypothesis: For all $m<n$, we have that $\sum_{j=1}^{m} (a(j)-a(j-1)) = a(m)-a(0)$.  Then \begin{align*}
    \sum_{j=1}^{n} (a(j)-a(j-1)) &= (a(n)-a(n-1)) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (a(j)-a(j-1)) \\
    &= (a(n)-a(n-1)) + (a(n-1)-a(0)) \\
    &= a(n) - a(n-1) + a(n-1) - a(0) \\
    &= a(n) - a(0)
\end{align*} which was to be shown.

Comment: The gods have blessed you Eric, thank you!